# Find a part of an element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Do you please know if it's possible in Python 3.7 to find in a list a certain word?
For example, in a list `list = ['hello world', 'hello everyone', 'Freddy Krueger']` to make the program do an action only for the element with the word 'hello' inside of them.
Sorry for my bad english, I hope you will help me finding a solution.
Have a nice evening!

Comment: What if the list includes something like `'Othello'`? Should that be a match for `'hello'`, or do you want only whole words? And what about case-sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

quick and easy way is to iterate over each string in the list, and then check if that string contains the word `hello`

```
for string in list:
    if 'hello' in string:
        #do something
```